# Parsing application.yml

Tags: java, spring, gradle, devops

Hi I try build my spring application with gradle and it gives bellow error code

> ERROR org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication - Application startup
> failed org.yaml.snakeyaml.scanner.ScannerException: mapping values are
> not allowed here  in 'reader', line 12, column 12:
> ssl:

The yml is

```
liquibase:
    changeLog: classpath:/config/liquibase/changelog/master-changelog.groovy

spring:
    datasource:
        url: jdbc:postgresql://x:xxxx/xxxxx
        username: x
        password: x

server:
    port: 8443
        ssl: 
            enabled: true
            key-store: classpath:keystore.p12
            key-store-password: x
            keyStoreType: pkcs12
            keyAlias: x

server:
    port: 8080
```

What is the error ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ssl and port should be on the same level, like so

```
server:
    port: 8443
    ssl: 
        enabled: true
        key-store: classpath:keystore.p12
        key-store-password: x
        keyStoreType: pkcs12
        keyAlias: x
    additionalPorts: 8080, 8081
```

Comment: Thanks, that work ! But now it gives the key "server" was duplicate. What I am trying to do is publish my application so that it runs with ssl, and I understand that in order for it to run on one port via http and on another port via https it must have these keys duplicated (as shown). Any idea what could it be ?